# Error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null' in form validation of angular 11 version

Tags: angular, angular11

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**
// app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup,  FormBuilder,  Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular Form Validation Tutorial';
   angForm: FormGroup;
   constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }
   createForm() {
    this.angForm = this.fb.group({
       name: ['', Validators.required ],
       address: ['', Validators.required ]
    });
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<!-- app.component.html -->

<div class="container">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!!
  </h1>
  <form [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" formControlName="name" type="text">
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].invalid && (angForm.controls['name'].dirty || angForm.controls['name'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].errors.required">
              Name is required.
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Address:</label>
            <input class="form-control" formControlName="address" type="text">
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['address'].invalid && (angForm.controls['address'].dirty || angForm.controls['address'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['address'].errors.required">
              email is required.
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit"
            [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid" class="btn btn-success">
            Save
        </button>
  </form>
  <br />
  <p>Form value: {{ angForm.value | json }}</p>
  <p>Form status: {{ angForm.status | json }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularvalidations and https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/8012/angular-form-validation-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using safe navigation operator "?"

```
<div *ngIf="angForm.controls['address'].invalid && (angForm.controls['address'].dirty || angForm.controls['address'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['address'].errors?.required">
              email is required.
            </div>
        </div>
```